# Creating transparent rectangle over form

Tags: vb.net, directx

Hey all i have this code that suppost to overlay a transparent rectangle over my form. Program is that i do not know what **"e"** should be set/defined as:

```
 e.Graphics.FillRectangle(color.fromargb(127.5,255,255,255), New Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100))
```

Any help would be great!

David

**update**

```
  ' Create solid brush.
    Dim blueBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)

    ' Create location and size of rectangle.
    Dim x As Single = 0.0F
    Dim y As Single = 0.0F
    Dim width As Single = 200.0F
    Dim height As Single = 200.0F
    ' Fill rectangle to screen.
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, x, y, width, height)
```

Comment: Your code seems to be C#. You tagged with VB.NET. Also, this has nothing to do with directX but rather the Graphix class.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3087655c-bd50-4408-9c55-dd179e442675/

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement that code in the Form's [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) method. `e` is of type `PaintEventArgs`.

Answer (score 1):

e represents the PaintEventAgrs that are passed as a parameter to the Paint eventhandler:

[Graphics.FillRectangle Method (Brush, Rectangle)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327634%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)